# Allowing TypeScript generic interfaces

Tags: typescript

I've got the following array of data which I'm trying to type properly.

```
const routes: IViewsRoute[] = [
    {
        data: {
            crumbs: (data: {page: CarPage}): BreadCrumbs => ({
                label: data.page.title
            }),
        }
    }
];
```

I've created an interface for this which looks something like the following:

```
interface IViewsRouteData extends Data {
    breadcrumbs?: (data: {page: CarPage}) => BreadCrumbs;
}

export interface IViewsRoute extends Route {
    data?: IViewsRouteData;
}
```

I want to use `IViewsRoute` for any of my routes, and in the example above the `CarPage` return can be multiple different interfaces, it could be `ManufacturePage` and so on. The following doesn't work, but this illustrates what I want to be able to do. While I've only put two page interfaces here, it really can be whatever. Ideally I want the route to define its own structure, only the arg names and the return type should be consistent.

```
const routes: IViewsRoute[] = [
    {
        data: {
            crumbs: (data: {page: ManufacturePage}): BreadCrumbs => ({
                label: data.page.title
            }),
        }
    }
];


interface IViewsRouteData extends Data {
    breadcrumbs?: (data: {page:  CarPage | ManufacturePage | unknown}) => BreadCrumbs;
}

export interface IViewsRoute extends Route {
    data?: IViewsRouteData;
}
```

Is there a way I can adjust `IViewsRouteData` to accept a generic type, so each route can define the properties it needs wherever `CarPage` is used, while the function still expects a specific return? I don't want to use `any`, and I've tried `unknown` but I get a compiler error. I can get around this for creating an interface for *every* route, but that feels like the wrong approach too as each route has overlap.

Comment: It sounds like you need to create a base class or interface that your "page" objects implement so that you can get the `data.page.title`.

Comment: The `page` is *optional*, so... that won't take you very far with solutions. If it weren't optional we could write a (helper) function to do the inferring for us (IViewsRoute would use generics).

Comment: If it wasn't optional, what would that solution look like? I'd be happy to adjust my original post to remove `page` as I think for the purpose of this I mostly care about the `data` arg

Comment: Is your question essentially "If I have a type `(foo: A | B | C) => void`, how can I make functions narrow their own foo parameter to just A, B, or C?"

Comment: Yeah, exactly that